# I am trying to find if a tree is a subtree of another tree and running into ArrayList comparison prolem

Tags: java, algorithm, tree

import java.util.*;

```
class TreeDemo
{

public static class Node
{
    int val;
    Node right, left;

    Node(int val)
    {
        this.val = val;
    }
}

public static class Tree{
    ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Node root;

    void insert(int val)
    {   
         if (root == null) 
        {
            root = new Node(val) ;
        }
        else{
            insertNode(val,root);
        }
    }

    void insertNode(int val, Node root)
    {
         if (root == null) 
        {
            root = new Node(val) ;
        }
         if (val < root.val)
        {
            if(root.left == null)
            {
                root.left = new Node(val) ;
            }
            else
            {
                insertNode(val, root.left);
            }
        }

        else if (val > root.val)
        {
            if(root.right == null)
            {
                root.right = new Node(val) ;
            }
            else
            {
                insertNode(val, root.right);
            }
        }


    }



    ArrayList<Node> preOrder(Node root)
    {   

        if(root!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(root.val);
            list.add(root);
        }
        if(root.left!=null)
        {

            preOrder(root.left);

        }
        if(root.right!=null)
        {

            preOrder(root.right);

        }
        return list;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{


    Tree t= new Tree();

    t.insert(5);
    t.insert(3);
    t.insert(7);
    t.insert(2);
    t.insert(4);
    t.insert(1);
    t.insert(7);
    t.insert(9);
    t.insert(6);



    Tree r = new Tree();
    r.insert(3);
    r.insert(2);
    r.insert(4);
    r.insert(1);

        List<Node> a = t.preOrder(t.root);
        System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------");
        List<Node> b = r.preOrder(r.root);

        if (a.containsAll(b))
```

this line does not seem to work for me or I am sure i might have made some mistake which I am not able to notice.

```
        {
            System.out.println("contains");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("does not contain");
        }

}
}
```

this is just a simple tree implementation in which I am adding all the node as they are encountered into a list and then checking if smaller string is a substring bigger string as this would give us that  the smaller tree would be a subtree of the bigger tree
thanks everyone for their help...

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Exception? Wrong output? If so, what is it and what is the expected output?

Comment: So the list b is contained in list a but ContainsAll is giving me a false ... m not sure where am I  making mistake...

Answer (score 2):

The implementation of `containsAll()` for `ArrayList` uses the `equals()` method of the type to determine if one list contains elements of the other.

You haven't overridden `equals()` for your `Node` class, so it's going to use the implementation from `Object`, which checks for reference equality.  This check is going to fail, since you create a **new** `Node` in your `insert()` method.

You need to override `equals()` and make it check for equality of the value contained in a `Node`.

Comment: good point !! BUT no luck  I changed  ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<>(); to  ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

and 
list.add(root.val); but still false

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what changes you've made exactly, but `containsAll()` on lists of `Integer` should work fine.  For instance, `List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2,3});
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(new Integer[]{1,2});
System.out.println(list1.containsAll(list2));` gives a value of `true`.

Comment: Regardless, the proper fix is to implement `equals()` on any class you want to be able to check for equality.